# Delete all Missed Calls log entries

Tags: android, calllog

Is there a way to delete ALL missed calls in the Call Log?

I have seen some posts where they tell you how to delete number by number. I just need to clear all of them (but just Missed calls, not Incoming and not Outgoing)

Thanks

Comment: Yes there is a way, described here: http://mobisoftinfotech.com/call-log-deletion-in-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following permissions in your manifest

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>`

Try the following code

`getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.CONTENT_URI , "type="+CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE , null);`

Based on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#TYPE

Comment: I get the error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot delete that URL: content://call_log

Comment: sorry.try this one    `getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),
    "type=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE, null);`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to retrieve the missed calls and then delete them.

Check [get-the-missed-call-list-and-delete-it-from-call-log-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771188/get-the-missed-call-list-and-delete-it-from-call-log-in-android).